# Toluenesulfonate vs. methylsulfonate

Tags: organic-chemistry, green-chemistry, organosulfur-compounds

Are there any advantages/disadvantages of using toluenesulfonate instead of methylsulfonate as a leaving group in E2 and SN2 reactions? I know they are both excellent leaving groups but how do they compare to each other? Is there a green chemistry aspect to it?

Thank you!

Answer (score 6):

- From the point of atom efficiency, methylsulfonate is advantageous compared to the *p*-toluenesulfonate.
- On the reagent itself, the methanesulfonate is more polar than the *p*-TsOH; so the later dissolves better in less polar organic solvents than the former.  Methanesulfonate even may be used to dissolve some metal salts.
- If used to generate a better leaving group, on workup, a methanesulfonate enters the aqueous phase easier than the tosylate.
- *p*-TsOH is a cheap, widely available solid (sometimes sold as hydrate) you may prepare by your own in large quantities; methanesulfonate however is a liquid, hence potentially easier to add continuously, and more expensive (even more so, per mL, the triflates).
- Methyl sulfonates are able to alkylate DNA, hence potentially carcinogen.  For tosylates, *currently* there is not such evidence (but obviously the dust of this strong acid is considered harmful).

As a personal note, among other reasons I found consultation of journals like [Organic Process Research & Development](http://pubs.acs.org/journal/oprdfk) just under this aspect (including green chemistry) as useful in two ways: i) publications describing how running a particular reaction *within a chain* of others works well / better than an other -- especially on larger scales of application--, and ii) the sections in line of "Some Items of Interest to Process R&D Chemists and Engineers".

**Addendum:**  There are dedicated compilations to figure out scope and limitations of chemical reagents.  To mention only two, [Fieser & Fieser](http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/book/10.1002/9780471264194) and [EROS](http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/book/10.1002/047084289X) edited by Leo Paquette (there is an e-EROS as electronic ressource, too) are multivolume references.

Comment: Do you have any citations at hand for literature on MSA alkylation of DNA?

Comment: @hBy2Py Thanks to NIH's policy, one I find in PubMed's data bases is Lundin et al. in Nucleic Acids Research, 2005, Vol. 33, No. 12
3799–3811, doi:10.1093/nar/gki681, found at https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC1174933/pdf/gki681.pdf

Answer (score 1):

In my experience mesylate forms more quickly using std conditions of MsCl/Et3N/DCM.